# How to run selenium script on remote machine using Jenkins

Tags: selenium

I've created a Selenium script in my local machine but we have to run this script in a remote server. What i would like to do is install Jenkins on this remote machine and then run my script on it 24 hours.

Is it possible to do this and if yes then how  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can use Jenkins to run your script "continuously", however the part of running it in a remote machine you can easily achive it while creating your WebDriver.

When you create your driver locally you do someting like `driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities)` however when you create a driver to communicate with a remote server you have to create a Remote Web Driver like  `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + REMOTE_URL + ":4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);`. For it to work tho, you have to have a selenium standalone server running in your REMOTE_URL.

For more Info take a look here: [WebDriver: Advanced Usage](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Hope it helps.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)
    {
   WebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(  new URL("http://115.248.81.2:4444/wd/hub"), 
           DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: I added the above code and when i run it , i get Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session.

Comment: The UnreachableBrowserException tells you exactly what the problem is. It can't find the browser.  As I said, you have to have a running selenium standalone server in 115.248.81.2 and the browser you are targeting installed on that machine. If it's a portable version, you have to specify the .exe through the capabilities. Please also read the referred link